# To show that $\bar{F}$ is connected , consequently, $F$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $E$ be a connected subset of a topological space $(X,\tau)$. If $F$ is subset of $X$ such that $E\subset F\subset \bar{F},$ then prove that $\bar{F}$ is connected , consequently, $F$ is onnected.

I am not able to solve it. Please, someone, help me

Comment: Don't think it's true. For example, let $X$ be $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology and $E$ be $\{0\}$ and $F$ be $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: In general, $\overline F$ need not be connected. And even if $\overline F$ is connected, $F$ need not be

Comment: You probably mean: suppose $F$ is connected and $F\subseteq E \subseteq \overline{F}$. Then $E$ is connected.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can you some example for both

Answer (score 0):

The question as stated is false.  Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ be the real line, let $E = [0,1]$ be the unit interval, and let $F = [0,1] \cup \lbrace 2 \rbrace = E \cup \lbrace 2 \rbrace$.

Then $E$ is connected and $F$ is not, since $F = [0,1] \cup \lbrace 2 \rbrace$ is itself a separation of $F$.  But $F$ is the union of two closed sets, so $F = \overline{F}$.  So this is a counterexample.

As someone else mentioned, I'm almost sure you mean the following:

If $E$ is a non-empty connected set and $E \subset F \subset \overline{E}$ then $F$ is connected (i.e. adding any stuff from the boundary of $E$ results in a set that is still connected).  You can prove this by contradiction; suppose that $E$ and $F$ are as stated, but by way of contradiction assume that $F = A \cup B$ is a separation of $F$.  Then by definition, $A$ and $B$ are both non-empty, and $\overline{A} \cap B = A \cap \overline{B} = \varnothing$.

Since $E$ is connected, it's contained entirely in either $A$ or $B$.  Without loss of generality, assume $E \subset A$, and since $E \neq \varnothing$ we have that $A$ is non-empty.  Since by our assumption $B$ is also not empty, suppose that $x \in B$ is a point in $B$.  Then $x \in \overline{E} \setminus E$ since $E$ is contained in $A$, and in particular $x \in \overline{E} \cap B \neq \varnothing$.  But $E \subset A$ and thus $\overline{A} \cap B \neq \varnothing$ since closures of subsets are contained in the closure of a larger set, a contradiction to $F = A \cup B$ being a separation!